# Meaning of "^[0-9]+.+[0-9]$" (R)

Tags: grep, regular-expression

(It's R programming)

You may refer to the sample question:

```
dates <- c("12/15/10", "12-2012", "12.2014", "1995")
grep(pattern = "^[0-9]+.+[0-9]$", x = dates)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you are using. Is that R code? How are we supposed to guess?

Comment: It's R. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54660845/i-need-help-understanding-the-pattern-code-in-the-grep-function

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes, I know that looks like R. But for all I know, the OP is trying to run this in a shell. Or using a specific regex flavor in R. Or using some other language with similar syntax. Depending on context, `[0-9]+` could mean "one or more digits" or it could mean "one digit, then a plus sign".

Comment: I put some tags and thought they would be referring to R. I'm sorry, will clarify next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *code* in the question makes no sense as I don't know what language it is written in.

The regular expression `^[0-9]+.+[0-9]$` is a POSIX extended regular expression that matches one or more digits at the start of the line, followed by one or more other characters (possibly including digits), and a final digit at the end of the line.

The components of the expression are:

- `^`, this anchors the expression to the start of a line.
- `[0-9]+`, this matches at least one character from the set `0-9`, i.e. digits.
- `.+`, this matches at least one character of any type.
- `[0-9]`, this matches a single digit.
- `$`, this anchors the expression to the end of the line.

An example of the shortest possible line that this expression matches:

```
1a1
```

All the example dates that I can see in the question code would additionally match the expression.  The following illustrates what part of the expression matches which part of the string (using `sed`):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "12/15/10" "12-2012" "12.2014" "1995" | sed -E 's/^([0-9]+)(.+)([0-9])$/(\1)(\2)(\3)/'
(12)(/15/1)(0)
(12)(-201)(2)
(12)(.201)(4)
(19)(9)(5)
```

Comment: Also, the first "+" is not required.

Comment: @berndbausch To match, no. But it matters if you care about what part of the expression matches what part of the query string.

Comment: ohh, so digit can also be considered as character? I was not sure about this. (Super thanks for your answer!)

Comment: @Coc_BA Yes, a digit is a character. In fact, all characters, including spaces and tabs and punctuation marks, and even control characters, are characters and are matched by the dot. Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.

Comment: You explanation is very clear and concise! Thank you so much!